# fetch() not returning first row

Tags: php, pdo, fetch

I am trying to update code that has been written using prepared statements.  This is my first time using them and I am having difficulty retrieving all the results.  When I use a direct SQL statement, it works so I don't think that's the problem.

The code will not return any results until there are at least two that match the query, then it will return all but the first row. I tried using fetchAll, but that gives different error about a call to an undefined method.

Thanks in advance for any help that you can provide.  If it's not to much to ask, please provide example or reference I can refer to and complete my understanding.

```
function html_competitive_make_gallery ($init) {
global $USER;
    $user_id     = $USER->id;
    $page_name = 'competitive';
    $base_name = $init['base_name'];

    global $link;
     $sql_pre = "SELECT form_id, community_id FROM frm_root WHERE user_id = ? 
AND page_name = ? ORDER BY last_modified_date DESC LIMIT 1";
     $stmt = $link->prepare($sql_pre);
     $stmt->bind_param('is', $user_id, $page_name);
     $stmt->execute();
     $stmt->bind_result($form_id,$community_id);
     $stmt->fetch();
     $stmt->close();
$sql = "SELECT data FROM tester WHERE type= '".$base_name."' 
AND form_id= '".$form_id ."' AND community_id= '". $community_id ."' LIMIT 5";
$stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($data);
$stmt->fetch();

$html[]='<div class="gallery" style ="width:100%;height:30%;overflow:hidden;">';


while ($stmt->fetch()){

                   echo $data;

                }
$stmt->close();

$html[]='</div>';

return implode ( $html);
}
```

Comment: Remove the `$stmt->fetch()` call after `bind_result`

Comment: Your code is extremely inconsistent. It contains stubs and pieces from other code. Can you clean it up? it's impossible to write working version out of this.

Comment: @IamDominic - Please ignore my comment (which I've already removed). I was thinking of something else.

Comment: @Your Common Sense, I'm trying. I inherited this code at a job I just started.  The entire script is written like this, its a nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running `fetch()` before entering your loop, hence dropping the first row of your results:

```
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($data);
$stmt->fetch();                    // <<< THIS LINE SHOULD NOT BE HERE

$html[]='<div class="gallery" style ="width:100%;height:30%;overflow:hidden;">';

while ($stmt->fetch()){
       echo $data;
}
$stmt->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while ($data = $stmt->fetch()){

               echo $data;

            }
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: That returns the number 1. That seems like it has both test results in the array but is only returning the second one.

Comment: Please note that [fetch()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) returns a boolean. From the description in the manual: *«Fetch results from a prepared statement into the bound variables»*

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is called "**mysqli**".
You will face such problems as long as you're using mysqli with prepared statements.

Just quit it and use PDO:

```
function html_competitive_make_gallery ($init) {
    global $USER;
    global $link;

    $sql_pre = "SELECT form_id, community_id FROM frm_root WHERE user_id = ? 
                AND page_name = ? ORDER BY last_modified_date DESC LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $link->prepare($sql_pre);
    $stmt->execute(array($USER->id, 'competitive'));
    return $stmt->fetch();
}
```

Comment: I strongly dislike mysqli's API myself but its prepared statements features are not broken as your answer suggests.